Metapost label with centered paragraph text
I'm using Metapost and trying to typeset a long-ish label (a figure caption so it could be multiple lines) centered under a figure and not exceeding the figure width.  I came up with this which is compiling but the paragraph is not centered:
% the width
numeric w;
w = ...;
% the TeX string for the caption typesetting
string s;
s = "\hbox to "
  & str[w]
  & "pt{\hfill\vbox{\hsize "
  & str[w-10]
  & "pt \parindent 0in Figure "
  & str[seq]
  & ". "
  & caption
  & "}\hfill}";
addto shipped also image (
  label.bot(TEX(s), z...);
);


where seq is an integer like 1, 2, ... and caption is the text of the caption.  So if the width w is 200pt the above will roughly work out to
s = "\hbox to 200pt{\hfill\vbox{\hsize 190pt \parindent 0in Figure 2. My caption}\hfill}"

This compiles and works as intended when the caption is long enough that it spills over the first line.  The paragraph is centered with 5pt margins from the figrure width on both left and right.
However, when the overall caption fits on a single line it is left-justified.
What am I doing wrong here?  How can I achieve the centered caption, regardless of whether one or multiple lines?
I think what I want for the \vbox \hsize is (i), exactly the text width when a single line, or w-10 pt when the caption is multiple lines.  But not sure how to express that.

You are making that much too complicated!

Here's a generic way to add a caption-like label, under the middle of whatever you have drawn.  And yes, it is automatically centered!
First, I strongly recommend that you do this using lualatex + luamplib instead of plain mpost. For the details see section 12 of Drawing with Metapost.
Start with a template like this.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
   % your diagram here
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

whatever you draw, compile it with lualatex and use your local PDF preview tool to look at the output.
To add a single-line centred caption, you can add this just before the endfig; line.
label.bot("My simple, short caption", point 1/2 of bbox currentpicture);

How does this work?

First, because you have got \mplibtextextlabel{enable} in the template, the <string> argument to label is automatically passed through LaTeX using whatever options and fonts you have asked for.

Second, point 1/2 of bbox currentpicture refers to the a point just below the centre of your drawing.  currentpicture refers to the, er, current picture, ie everything that is about to be shipped out by endfig.  bbox currentpicture is then a rectangular cyclic path around that <picture> object, that starts at the lower left corner.   So point 1/2 of that path is exactly in the middle of the bottom of the picture.   You can (of course) control the size of the bbox with the parameter bboxmargin.  The default value is 4bp.

Third, the magic of the label macro, with the bot suffix, will automatically centre the text below the point specified.


Here is a complete example:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  draw fullcircle scaled 100;
  label.bot("My simple, short caption", point 1/2 of bbox currentpicture);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

compile this with lualatex to get this:

If you want a multiline caption, the procedure is much the same except that you need to wrap the text in enough LaTeX code to make a centred multiline label.   Here is one simple way to do that:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  draw fullcircle scaled 100;
  label.bot(btex \begin{tabular}{c}
   The first line of my long caption runs this far\\
   and continues after the line break used above.
\end{tabular} etex, point 1/2 of bbox currentpicture);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

which produces this:

If you don't want to insert manual line breaks, then you have to do just a little more work:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  draw fullcircle scaled 100;
  label.bot(btex \vbox{\hsize=3in\begin{center}
   The first line of my long caption runs this far
   and is automatically wrapped to a second line.
\end{center}} etex, point 1/2 of bbox currentpicture);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}


Of course you may want to adjust the \hsize to suit your picture.

Thanks for the detailed reply, that's a lot to take in and will take me some time to digest it.  My workflow is plain tex so not sure I can switch the the Lua workflow you recommended but I will investigate nevertheless.  Thanks again, cheers!

You can do all that with plain TeX -- plain luatex that is...  you might like to read the luamplib documentation -- try texdoc luamplib.
